# gdb Objective-C No Symbol Table

Tags: objective-c, gdb, symbols

I have to debug a Cocoa/Objective-C app that has had its symbols stripped. I am pretty well versed in gdb and Objective-C. Normally, I use tools like otool or class-dump to find out what I need to make debugging a little easier. For example, class-dump makes it easy to know where, at runtime, certain methods live.

My question is: Can I "help" gdb provide better symbolic information at runtime when looking at backtraces? In the following backtrace I know (from using class-dump) what all of the methods marked as "??" are. It would be great if I could get gdb to do this for me.

Thanks!

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x960de54e in -[NSPersistentUIManager init] ()
#1  0x960de489 in __PersistentUIManager_block_invoke_1 ()
#2  0x9abd0693 in _NSFaultInObject ()
#3  0x960ad800 in +[NSPersistentUIManager sharedManager] ()
#4  0x961aefac in -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] ()
#5  0x961aeefd in -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] ()
#6  0x96238acc in -[NSWindow orderFront:] ()
#7  0x0000a032 in ?? ()
#8  0x9154bdaa in -[NSObject performSelector:] ()
#9  0x9154bd27 in -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] ()
#10 0x960c16a7 in -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] ()
#11 0x960b744d in loadNib ()
#12 0x960b6834 in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] ()
#13 0x960b673e in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] ()
#14 0x960b6672 in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] ()
#15 0x9633d6c7 in NSApplicationMain ()
#16 0x00002cc6 in ?? ()
#17 0x00002bed in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the symbol tables that were generated at the time of the build;  typically, the .dSYM folder(s).   With those, you can `add-symbol-table` in GDB and it'll generally figure things out a bit more.

You can't really produce the symbol tables after the fact.   Many developers will archive off a copy of the symbol tables for various production releases of their app such that crash traces can be symbolicated and reproducible crashes (that only reproduce on production builds or a particular client install) can be debugged more easily.

The ?? frames are, most likely, C functions for which there are no symbols -- certainly #16 and #17 are _start() and main(). #7 is likely some CF goober used for the -performSelector: internals.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be great if I could get gdb to do this for me.

I expect you should be able to. (I haven't done this for Objective-C, only for plain-C, but I can't imagine there will be any difference).

For `C`, suppose you want to teach GDB that `foobar()` is at address `0x12345678`. Then:

```
echo 'void foobar() { }' | gcc -c -xc- -o foobar.o
(gdb) add-symbol-file foobar.o 0x12345678
```

(This works because in relocatable `foobar.o` the address of `foobar()` would normally be `0`.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In the Mach-O file there in an __OBJC segment that contains *all* of the information required to map method IMPs to address locations. There shouldn't need to be any "hoop jumping" that is required for C. gdb should be able to figure this out on its own.

Comment: It'll only show what is shown in the backtrace that OP already showed;  without symbol tables, you won't get line #s, variable names, etc....   The ?? frames are, most likely, C functions for which there are no symbols -- certainly #16 and #17 are _start() and main().   #7 is likely some CF goober used for the -performSelector: internals.